# Spring boot restful webservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My spring boot restful web services is working even though  stopped running microsoft sqlserver database in my services. How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

There might be below reason.

1. You might be using some kind of cache so still response is coming form cache even your db is down.
2. You might be checking services which are not required db transaction..

OR if you are only referring you application is continue to running then might be `spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true` has been set. or you might have some defined `data source validations properties` to at-least continue run app and whenever db is back, it will established a connection.